# Why I should create separate project for ReactJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I want to use React for front end and Express for backend in my new web application.

According to guides I have to create subproject with *create-react-app* tool in my project directory:

```
my-project
|-frontend
| |-package.json
| |-components
| | |-...
| | 
| |-...
|
|-backend
| |-api
| | |-...
| |-app.js
| |-...
|
|-package.json
```

While development, I should launch two servers on different ports, for backend and for frontend, and proxy requests to backend throw *React* server.

This scheme looks very ugly to me. How can I configure backend server to provide the same functionality as *react-scripts* does, to avoid using a separate server for it

Comment: It's because the React development server is providing development functionality, such as hot-reloading not behaving like your real client code would. Running your backend server separately will ease your development & deploy experience, since you get to treat your server as its "own thing" while developing, which is true to the real ecosystem. don't burden your server code with Client-side development tools

Answer (score 5):

Having to separate folders (for backend and for frontend) will give you a clearer and scalable structure for your project.

In your backend create a *package.json* file and inside a script section with:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"  // the command you use to run your project
}
```

---

The way you can run both projects in the same script:

Install **npm-run-all** package

```
$ npm install npm-run-all --save-dev
```

Then in your file *my-project/package.json* you should have something like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start:server": "cd backend && npm start",
  "start:client": "cd frontend && npm start",
  "start": "npm-run-all --parallel start:client start:server"
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

It is good to separate Front and Backend,
It increases the maintainability
 and if you want you can serve front-end as a root . And all your rest end points in a single server.